# Drop one to one relationship tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created two tables which are 1 to 1.
So one table has foreign key from another.

How can I drop the tables? I did not use on delete cascade while creating tables.

So I either have to somehow change it, or IDK..

I have done this.

```
CREATE TABLE hotel(
id_hotel
...

)

CREATE TABLE Manager(
ID_Manager
...
id_hotel FOREIGN KEY ...
)
```

and then I added

```
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD id_manager INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_manager) REFERENCES Manager(id_manager);
```

Comment: Can you add the schema you have to your question? That might help people give you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to drop the table with the foreign key in the column, eg: If you have 2 entities one named driving_license and the other person, and you store the id from person in the table driving_license, you have to first drop the table driving_license

Or if you are using MySQL: You can write:

```
SET_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

//Drop however you want

SET_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

For MSSQL you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtablename> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

And then drop your table

Comment: Nope I have two entities for example driving_license and person. I stored id person to driving_license and id driving_license to person

Comment: Nope, I think you dont understand me. I created one entityHotel, then I created entity Manager. Manager had foreign key id_hotel. and then I added id_manager to Hotel as a foreign key

Comment: 1) Why did you do this? 2) Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 1) I accidently created two foreign keys in Hotel (with slightly different names). so I want to delete one of them or drop table.   2)Sql server managament studio

Comment: I might just let it be and create new tables, but for future work I want to know how to fix it, or how to create it correctly